# In which countries can I find spiders as traditional dishes?

Tags: food-and-drink, culture, insects

I like experiencing different cultures. When I'm travelling I try to be part of the culture. It means I try to meet local people and make friends, as well as understanding the customs and the culture.

Part of the culture is the food. I would like to know where I can find insects to eat, like spiders, as traditional dishes?

[image]

Comment: Almost every country in the world has insects to eat - even reserved countries like NZ, Aus, Canada, US I've seen spiders, crickets, locusts, grubs and more.  This is way too broad IMHO.

Comment: @MarkMayo I think the OP is asking about which cultures are known to have insects as part of their cuisine, in which the OP wishes to try said cuisines. Not literally which countries have insects that are edible

Comment: @EdmundYeung99 sure, but off the top of my head - NZ has huhu grubs, Aus has witchity grubs, Cambodia, Vietnam, Thailand have spiders, crickets and more, I've had bugs in Canada and US, and UK....and South Africa...and Morocco....so it's still fairly broad...

Comment: @MarkMayo totally agree, but the OP has narrowed it down by listing 3 specific insects, granted that list could still be quite large.  Would you recommend 3 different questions, one for each insect?

Comment: @Afetter according to Wikipedia [Entomophagy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entomophagy) is the human consumption of insects, known to be eaten in 80% of the world's nations...

Comment: I edited the question to try make it more clear.

Comment: Spiders aren´t insects.

Comment: If you are looking for spiders on the menu, Cambodia is your destination. Skuon in particular, where you'll find platters of tarantulas at bus stops and markets. They apparently started eating the spiders our of necessity under the Khmer Rouge regime, and developed a taste for them. I tried myself and they are quite palatable, to be honest not very different from other fried creepy crawlies (scorpions, termite alates, grasshoppers). If you have the stomach for that definitely worth a try. And while you're at it check out the wonders and horrors of Cambodia.

Comment: i have tried deep fried spider and bat and crocodile soup in a Thai zoo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Deep-fried tarantulas** are a specialty of [Skuon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skuon), Cambodia:

[image]
*"[Skun spiders closeup](http://flickr.com/photos/soschilds/375166267/)" by A. www.viajar24h.com -  Licensed under CC BY 2.0 via [Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Skun_spiders_closeup.jpg#/media/File:Skun_spiders_closeup.jpg).*

How "traditional" this is is disputed: apparently this dish came to be out of necessity during the Khmer Rouge years, and has lived on as a novelty.  They're not regularly eaten anywhere in Cambodia (or the world) that I know of.

Answer (score 2):

You can eat ants in Colombia.

You can eat a whole bunch of different types of creepy crawlies in Thailand.

You can eat locusts in much of southern Africa.

Comment: And Australia (wichity grubs), NZ (huhu grubs), just about every country on earth. This is way too broad a question :/

Comment: you can eat ants anywhere in the world? or do Colombian ants have *something extra* added as seasoning?

Comment: I take that comment back, apparently **Hormigas Culonas** is a thing in Colombia :)

Comment: Indeed, Edmund. :) keep in mind that you can pretty much eat anything anywhere. But not everywhere is everything considered a delicacy.